# Get language of string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have a title string, written in different languages.

Is there way to check which language is each string?

Comment: Are you talking of spoken languages like english, spanish, chinese? If this is a serious question you should know, that the task is generally impossible to decide for an algorithm. Heuristics might give you a clue and the longer phrases lead to better results, take a look at [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670427/how-does-language-detection-work)

Comment: Maybe https://developers.google.com/translate/ or http://developer.yahoo.com/r3/ ?

Answer (score 7):

I have not played with it but you should look at [NSLinguisticTagger](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and its `- (NSOrthography *)orthographyAtIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)effectiveRange` method. From the [NSOrthography docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOrthography_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOrthography):

> The NSOrthography class describes the linguistic content of a piece of
>   text, typically used for the purposes of spelling and grammar
>   checking.
>
> An NSOrthography instance describes:
>
> Which scripts the text contains. A dominant language and possibly
>   other languages for each of these scripts. A dominant script and
>   language for the text as a whole. Scripts are uniformly described by
>   standard four-letter tags (Latn, Grek, Cyrl, etc.) with the supertags
>   Jpan and Kore typically used for Japanese and Korean text, Hans and
>   Hant for Chinese text; the tag Zyyy is used if a specific script
>   cannot be identified. See Internationalization Programming Topics for
>   more information on internationalization.
>
> Languages are uniformly described by BCP-47 tags , preferably in
>   canonical form; the tag und is used if a specific language cannot be
>   determined.

Comment: I didn't know about this, will look into it.anybody used it for the described purpose? Interesting

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the [Google Transalate REST API](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#detect-language) to find the language.

And you can use something like [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) to make the REST requests to the google servers.

Comment: Good solution for a complicated task. +1 - but might still generate unreliable results. @Devfly can the string be anything at all? Where does it come from?

Comment: It comes from articles and web pages. I think that this should do it. But i'll also take a look at NSOrtography!

Comment: @Mario the Google API supports unicode characters. So unless some one is writing something in Russian in Thai script :P , I believe this should work!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [N-gram sampling frequencies techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). I am not an expert, but they are rumored to work well in practice.

See [netspeak](http://www.netspeak.org/) and papers like [this](http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/W/W11/W11-0813.pdf) etc etc.

Comment: This page has a fairly good list of ngrams that identifies several languages: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10261

Answer (score 0):

There's Google translation API available that allows language conversation. I am sure there must be something you will find that returns matched language for your string. See [Google Translate APIs](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone) for details.